# How to graph Taylor polynomials by hand?

Tags: taylor-expansion, graphing-functions

What techniques exist for drawing Taylor polynomials by hand?

I've been pointed to have a look at a theorem about the $n$th derivative test and its proof (e.g. [p.3. here](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/people/academic/Steve.Russ/cs131/NOTE26.PDF)), but I am unsure about how to use it.

Comment: Perhaps the above theorem tells about the concavity of the Taylor polynomial. Since one knows where the polynomial is evaluated, e.g. $x_0$, then the polynomials are fixed to $f(x)$ at this point, but then concavity tells us how the polynomial "bends" from that point. I.e. whether the polynomial curves above or below f(x) and what kind of "curve" it makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific method to draw Taylor polynomials, which can be handled like ordinary polynomials.

Just one thing: at the point of evaluation, the Taylor polynomial (at least quadratic) has the same *value*, the same *slope* and the same *curvature*. Higher order constraints have no simple geometric interpretations better than "staying close to the true curve".

Below an illustration with the exponential and constant, linear and quadratic expansions.

[image]

The cubic approximation starts being undistinguishable.

[image]